# sql query for a particular field displaying start time in database'

Tags: mysql

```
+------+----------+
| ACP  | Time     |
+------+----------+
|    0 | 00:01:32 |
|    0 | 00:02:58 |
|    0 | 00:04:20 |
|    0 | 00:05:41 |
|    0 | 00:07:00 |
|    0 | 00:08:19 |
|    0 | 00:09:44 |
|    0 | 00:11:05 |
|    0 | 00:12:26 |
|    0 | 00:13:43 |
|    0 | 00:15:04 |
|    0 | 00:16:29 |
|    0 | 00:17:45 |
|    0 | 00:19:07 |
|    0 | 00:20:27 |
|    0 | 00:21:49 |
|    0 | 00:23:14 |
|    0 | 00:24:32 |
|    0 | 00:25:57 |
|    0 | 00:27:13 |
|    0 | 00:28:38 |
|    0 | 00:30:00 |
|    0 | 00:31:16 |
|    0 | 00:32:42 |
```

It is the data what i get i should display starting time from query.

Comment: By "starting time" you mean the smallest timestamp? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question it's best to explain both what you're starting with and trying to accomplish. In this case it's hard to tell whether your sample data is the input -- the table contents -- or the output. It's also helpful to explain your purpose. For example, "These are a list of race runners. Each row shows the time the runner crossed the starting line."